# MVC PagedList for dynamic generated item with specified page given

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Model of answers that user provided for the specified question. The Question field are dynamicaly passed to answer model and generated one by one on answer view.
In my question model user are able to create the page and order of each question.
This is the model of answer and question :
Question :

```
[Key]
public int QuestionId { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Order { get; set; }
public string Page { get; set; }
```

Answer :

```
[Key]
public int AnswerId { get; set; }
public int QuestionId { get; set; }
public string Answer { get; set; }
```

And this is how im Showing each Question to user and getting the answer for them :

```
@model IEnumerable<A.Models.Question>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Set", "AddAnswer"))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@{
int cnt = 0;
foreach (A.Models.Question item in Model)
 {
<label>@item.Title</label>
<textarea id="B_@cnt" name="a_@item.QuestionId" data-val="true" data-val-length=""100"><textarea>
 cnt++;
}
```

And My Controller :

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(context.AddAnswer.ToList());
    }

public ActionResult Set(FormCollection fc)
    {
        AContext db = new AContext();
        var Answer = fc.AllKeys
        .Where(k => k.StartsWith("a_"))
        .ToDictionary(k => k, k => fc[k]);
.....
}
```

now finally my questions :

1-is it possible to show paged view based on question information. like Page= "The page that question must be showed" and order="The order of question on specified page" ?
2-is it possible to avoid postback when showing the pagedlist on the method above? like when we have 10 question in 2 page , and  we answer 1 page then going to second one and ... and in finall page we send all them back to controller at once. plus we have the ability to navigate back and forth into pages and have the the answers there.

Thanks :)