# Pagination on multiple table as a row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to have pagination on multiple table like each table as a one row ?
I have a (Foreach) in my MVC view that generates one table for each of elements(dynamic control,textbox,etc..)
its like about 50 or more table in my page ,
now is it possible to get pagination on my view ? like 6 table on each page? plus forward and backward button.
btw im avoiding post back so all table input must be send at once after final page entry.
thanks in forward

i have a model like this :

BaseForm model=> "For saving Base Form , like what type of form should it be(exam,Survey,or fillout type) Plus the userId of FormBuilder"
Question model=> "For Saving question and type of them, plus it have the BaseForm ID and field that have the true answer"

Answer Model=> "The public form for answering the question or survey or filling form that keeps the user entry plus the uniqecode for each user"

ViewModelForAnswer model => "That just show the resault of the user by linq query. it gets the current admin user id and join the three table(question,answer,Base) with that condition and show the final resualt like how many true answer per user we have , or survey result.

Thanks :)

Comment: ins't that the same as paging but only show 1 row per page?

Comment: yeah its exactly the paging , but each row is a whole table and there a multiple row in each page

Comment: then I don't get what you want from us ...

Comment: sorry im kinda elementry in english , let me simpilify my question.
I have a lots of Table in 1 page.
now i want to have a client soultion to make these tables be pagable.
btw , when im saying pageable i mean each table as a one row and not paging inside each table.

Comment: ok, so what did you tried so far? you can't expect us to give you code, here we help others...

Comment: Thank u for helping , ok heres what i have done so far :

this is my Method and first view plus my model :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312697/mvc-pagedlist-for-dynamic-generated-item-with-specified-page-given

then ive changed the view like this (plus its now one table and many row) :

http://paste2.org/4vsG9P8c

thanks

Comment: why dont you have a table for questions, one for answers, and one for user answers where all you save is `QuestionId`, `AnswerId`, `UserId`? it will be easier to handle, no? I have a web application that works just like that, Admin saves questions with multiple answers and I need to save the user answer, plus give feedback to the admin witch users answered correctly so they can choose a winner...

Comment: hmm is table mean db table ? 
i putting some info about my model in the main question 
thanks if forward :)